# jQuery prevent rapid clicking

Tags: jquery, settimeout

i've got an issue with my code.
I've got a .click function, and i want to disable it during the animation (to prevent rapid clicking) inside that function. I've tested everything i found in internet. Thanks for help!

```
$('#content').click(function() {

    if($('#content').hasClass('closed')){
            $('#content').animate({
            height: '300px',
            }, 1000, 'easeInQuint', function() {
            $('#content').css("background-image", "url(http://torm.vot.pl/breitenbach/templates/breitenbachmedia/images/arrows_down.png)");
            });
            $('#content').removeClass('closed');
            $('#content').addClass('open');
        } 



    else {
            $('#content').animate({
            height: '150px',
            }, 1000, 'easeInQuint', function() {
            $('#content').css("background-image", "url(http://torm.vot.pl/breitenbach/templates/breitenbachmedia/images/arrows.png)");

            });
            $('#content').removeClass('open');
            $('#content').addClass('closed');

        }       
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try using a flag like this:

```
var stopClick = false;
$('#content').click(function () {
    if(stopClick) return;
    stopClick = true;
    if ($('#content').hasClass('closed')) {
        $('#content').animate({
            height: '300px',
        }, 1000, 'easeInQuint', function () {
            $('#content').css("background-image", "url(http://torm.vot.pl/breitenbach/templates/breitenbachmedia/images/arrows_down.png)");
            stopClick = false;
        });
        $('#content').removeClass('closed');
        $('#content').addClass('open');
    } else {
        $('#content').animate({
            height: '150px',
        }, 1000, 'easeInQuint', function () {
            $('#content').css("background-image", "url(http://torm.vot.pl/breitenbach/templates/breitenbachmedia/images/arrows.png)");
            stopClick = false;
        });
        $('#content').removeClass('open');
        $('#content').addClass('closed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to prevent this because of the animation, you can use `.is(':animated')`:

```
$('#content').click(function() {
    if(!$('#content').is(':animated')){ // If the element is not animate, do something.
        if($('#content').hasClass('closed')){
            $('#content').animate({
                height: '300px',
            }, 1000, 'easeInQuint', function() {
                $('#content').css("background-image", "url(http://torm.vot.pl/breitenbach/templates/breitenbachmedia/images/arrows_down.png)");
            });
            $('#content').removeClass('closed');
            $('#content').addClass('open');
        } 



        else {
            $('#content').animate({
                height: '150px',
            }, 1000, 'easeInQuint', function() {
                $('#content').css("background-image", "url(http://torm.vot.pl/breitenbach/templates/breitenbachmedia/images/arrows.png)");

            });
            $('#content').removeClass('open');
            $('#content').addClass('closed');

        }  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your page by:
adding css for `open` and `closed` classes

```
#content{
    height:150px;
}

#content.open {
    background: url("http://torm.vot.pl/breitenbach/templates/breitenbachmedia/images/arrows.png");
}

#content.closed {
    background: url("http://torm.vot.pl/breitenbach/templates/breitenbachmedia/images/arrows_down.png");
}
```

Then, using [`toggleClass("closed open")`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) you are able to change backgrounds.

Finally, you can use [`$this.is(":animated")`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector to check does current element is animating by `jQuery.animate()`

So, for this html

```
<div id="content"
    class="closed">
</div>
```

, previously described css and following JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#content', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if(!$this.is(":animated")){
        $this.animate({
                height: $this.hasClass('closed') ? "300px" : "150px"
            },
            500,
            'easeInQuint',
            function() {
                    $this.toggleClass("closed open");
            }
        );
    }
});
```

you can fulfill your requirements.

## Demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/A77AV/).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has no issues with adding some beautiful plugins to their project then i would recommend [Ladda](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda)  [Buttons with built-in loading indicators, effectively bridging the gap between action and feedback].

This will not only displaying loading indicators on DOM element , i will also take care of rapid clicks issues